# Finding the sum of integers from multiple mysql rows in same column

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I have a table for users and a column that stores an integer. I want to take all rows from that table and find the sum of them. The only way I can think to do this would be to loop through all the rows and add them together one by one. However, that seems quite inefficient and I'm sure there's a better way.

Anyone know of one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(COLUMN_NAME) as total FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(column) FROM Users;
```

Should work. Hope it helps!
Also, refer to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp.

Answer (score 2):

```
select SUM(col_1) as sum from table_name  GROUP BY col_2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) as req_value FROM the_req_table;
```

It will directly give you the sum